# Apply Text Color Gradient During Text Output Animation (HTML, CSS, JS) without showing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gradient

I have a text animation that loads when the page loads. The text will be written to the screen character by character, I want to have some words with a gradient applied. I have been able to successfully apply the gradient, however, it pauses when it first gets to the `span` tag and then outputs each character with the gradient after the pause (seemingly the length of outputting each character)

I created a CodePen with the closest working version to the requirements. View Code: https://codepen.io/Kelly-Gold/pen/oNPJQXo

I managed to capture a screenshot at the beginning and end of the gradient so you can see the unexpected/unwanted HTML characters
When the line is complete, the output is what I desired, but it's not fluid, and shows unwanted characters along the way.

**Text when output arrives at span tag**
[image]

**Text when output finishes gradient and arrives at closing span tag**
[image]

**Text when output reaches end of line**
[image]

I can't figure out how to make it smooth without pausing, and without showing the characters at the beginning and closing of the `span` tag

**Requirements/Desired output**

1. Each line is output character by character, with pause at end of line
2. Some words can have a gradient
3. The output does not pause when it arrives at a gradient word, so it should flow just like the regular black text
4. No HTML tag characters should be visible at runtime

Comment: `I can't figure out how to...` when you get to the start of a tag, change letterCount to point to the character after the end of that tag.

Comment: @James could you please provide an example of the code change? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question, not only on an external site like Code Pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution, thanks to @james for guidance on how to handle the span tags inside the JS

```js
const lines = [
  "Hi, I'm <span class='gradient'>Kelly</span>",
  "I like to try <span class='gradient'>new tech</span>, learn new stuff, and get outdoors.",
  "Currently a <span class='gradient'>Solutions Engineer</span> connecting app ecosystems via API.",
];

let lineCount = 0;
let letterCount = 0;
let currentText = "";

const textElements = [
  document.querySelector(".line1"),
  document.querySelector(".line2"),
  document.querySelector(".line3")
];

function type() {
  if (letterCount === 0) {
    // Start blinking cursor when typing begins on a new line
    textElements[lineCount].classList.add('cursor');
  }

  if (letterCount === lines[lineCount].length) {
    // Stop blinking cursor when typing ends on a line
    textElements[lineCount].classList.remove('cursor');
    textElements[lineCount].classList.add('cursor-blink');
    pauseTyping();
    return;
  }

  letterCount++;
  currentText = lines[lineCount];

  const startOpenGradient = currentText.indexOf("<span class='gradient'>");
  const endOpenGradient = startOpenGradient + "<span class='gradient'>".length;
  const startCloseGradient = currentText.indexOf("</span>");
  const endCloseGradient = startCloseGradient + "</span>".length;

  if (letterCount === startOpenGradient)
    letterCount = endOpenGradient;
  else if (letterCount === startCloseGradient)
    letterCount = endCloseGradient;

  currentText = lines[lineCount].slice(0, letterCount);
  textElements[lineCount].innerHTML = currentText;

  setTimeout(type, 100);
}

function pauseTyping() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    textElements[lineCount].classList.remove('cursor-blink');
    letterCount = 0;
    lineCount++;

    if (lineCount === lines.length) {
      // Make the cursor blink indefinitely at the end of the last line
      textElements[lineCount - 1].classList.add('cursor-blink');
      return;
    }

    type();
  }, 2000); // Change to 2000 for a 2-second pause between lines
}

type();
```

```css
.text-animation {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.line { /* Add this class to apply margin to each line */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Adjust the space between lines */
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFC107, #FF5733);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.cursor::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 3px;
  opacity: 1; /* Change the initial opacity to 0 */
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%, 50% { opacity: 1; }
  50.01%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.no-cursor::after {
  content: none;
}
.cursor-blink::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-left: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: blink 0.75s infinite;
}
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Typing Animation with Blinking Cursor</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="text-animation">
    <div class="line">
      <h1 class="line1 text-container cursor"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <h1 class="line2 text-container"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <h1 class="line3 text-container"></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does a check to see if the letterCount is at the start of either <span... or </span..., and if so it adjusts letterCount to point to the character following the end of that tag.

This is by no means perfect.  One problem is that when we write out the html from between the opening and closing span tags, we don't include a closing span tag.  I also broke the blink thing.

```js
const lines = [
  "This is the first line",
  "This is the second line with a <span class='gradient'>gradient</span> word",
  "This is the last line with a <span class='gradient'>gradient</span> word",
];


let lineCount = 0;
let letterCount = 0;
let currentText = "";
let isCursorBlinking = true;

const textElement1 = document.querySelector(".line1");
const textElement2 = document.querySelector(".line2");
const textElement3 = document.querySelector(".line3");

function type() {
  if (letterCount === lines[lineCount].length) {
    pauseTyping();
    return;
  }

  letterCount++;
  currentText = lines[lineCount];
  
  const startOpenGradient = currentText.indexOf("<span class='gradient'>");
  const endOpenGradient = startOpenGradient + "<span class='gradient'>".length;
  const startCloseGradient = currentText.indexOf("</span>");
  const endCloseGradient = startCloseGradient + "</span>".length;
  
  
  if (letterCount === startOpenGradient)
    letterCount = endOpenGradient;
  else if (letterCount === startCloseGradient)
    letterCount = endCloseGradient;
  
  currentText = lines[lineCount].slice(0, letterCount);

    textElement1.innerHTML = currentText;

  isCursorBlinking = true;
  textElement3.classList.toggle("blink");

  
  
  setTimeout(type, 100);
}

function pauseTyping() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    letterCount = 0;
    lineCount++;

    if (lineCount === lines.length) {
      return;
    }

    type();
  }, 1000);
}

type();
```

```css
.text-animation {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.blink {
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFC107, #FF5733);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-animation">
  <h1 class="line1"></h1>
  <h1 class="line2"></h1>
  <h1 class="line3"></h1>
</div>
```